# pandas output every line

Tags: python, pandas, output

i just study pandas two days, i read a csv example file, and output every line, it like this:

```
              a     b     c    d     e    f     g
     0  1980/81  1182  5408  292  7248  174  2212
     1  1981/82  1098  5112  257  7316  242  1936
     2  1982/83  1156  5701  330  8567  124  1802
     3  1983/84   993  4265  391  8905  141  1078
     4  1984/85  1182  5364  217  5813  343  4313
```

this is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('uk_rain_2014.csv', header=0)
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
print df.head(5)
```

how can i do to print every like this:

```
         a     b     c    d     e    f     g
   1980/81  1182  5408  292  7248  174  2212
   1981/82  1098  5112  257  7316  242  1936
   1982/83  1156  5701  330  8567  124  1802
   1983/84   993  4265  391  8905  141  1078
   1984/85  1182  5364  217  5813  343  4313
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
print df.to_string(index=False)
```

Output:

```
a     b     c    d     e    f     g
1980/81  1182  5408  292  7248  174  2212
1981/82  1098  5112  257  7316  242  1936
1982/83  1156  5701  330  8567  124  1802
1983/84   993  4265  391  8905  141  1078
1984/85  1182  5364  217  5813  343  4313
```

OR

```
print(df.to_csv(sep='\t',index=False))
```

Output:

```
a       b       c       d   e       f   g
1980/81 1182    5408    292 7248    174 2212
1981/82 1098    5112    257 7316    242 1936
1982/83 1156    5701    330 8567    124 1802
1983/84 993     4265    391 8905    141 1078
1984/85 1182    5364    217 5813    343 4313
```